# How to type a foreign language author name with special characters?

Tags: university, undergraduate

How do you cite (in APA) the authors last name when it is a foreign language with special unknown characters that can't be identified by most word processors.

Comment: _characters that can't be identified by most word processors_ How did the journal print it?

Comment: If you want to get the most helpful answer then you may benefit from saying what the character is, and what language it comes from. It may be worth looking how it's been cited in existing publications though.

Comment: Most modern word processors support Unicode, which contains code points for the characters of basically every language on Earth. So unless your co-author is Klingon, I find it difficult to believe that your word processor does not support these characters. Maybe it is a problem with the font that you are using. (By the way, there is a proposal to include the Klingon alphabet in Unicode).

Comment: You take the necessary steps to make sure that you *can* type the character in your word processor. In this day and age computers can represent pretty much every script used (remember people in your author's country also use word processors from day to day).

Comment: Have you tried closet English equivalent? For example leaving an accent mark or similar.

Comment: @Greg if you do that, the citation won't be correct and harder to connect to the author's work

Comment: @Greg There's also the question of what's an accent mark that can be left out and what's an integral part of the letter that might look like an accent mark to others. For example in my language we have common issues with c, ć and č. In Latin, they look similar and foreigners tend to think of them as a variations of a same letter, but they're different and in original versions, it's quite easy to see the difference: ц,ћ,ч.

Comment: @Greg Then we also have the Đ letter. If you leave out -, you'll rename George into Dorde, which makes no sense and instead a different transliteration of Djordje is used, which probably won't be immediately obvious if you don't know the language.

Comment: @Emilie Many reference database cannot handle such characters, so it is an issue that already exist, without OP doing anything and most probably handled by the author manually.

Comment: @AndrejaKo If you don't like how foreigners spell your name, use a professional name with reasonably clear spelling, it is that simple. If we don't asume foreigners shoudl be able to read Chinese or Japanese character sets, we shouldn't assume they read other character sets ( of much more minor languages). I use standardized name for professional purposes, others can use too.

Comment: @Greg Or people could figure out that it's 21st century, not 19th and that other cultures exist too and not assume things about them. Also database point mentioned in the other comment is completely moot. If a database can't accept a Unicode name, maybe it's time for an update.

Comment: @Greg: "If we don't asume foreigners shoudl be able to read Chinese or Japanese character sets, we shouldn't assume they read other character sets ( of much more minor languages)." - I have thought about that reasoning various times before, but I have come to the conclusion that people do not think in "character sets". Character sets are somwhat arbitrary, and arguably, Unicode is just one big character set, anyway. People rather think in scripts. Seen like that, it seems indeed reasonable that someone using Latin script should be able to use a previously unknown diacritic on a Latin letter.

Comment: Some foreign languages don't include strange letters like J, K, Q, W, X, Y in their alphabets. But usually they have the courtesy to represent English names properly. Why shouldn't we do the same for their letters?

Answer (score 9):

Try shapecatcher.com and detexify.kirelabs.org to identify the characters.  Then proceed from there by inserting a Unicode char in a Unicode font or a latex command (depending on whether you are using MSWord or some form of LaTeX).  Once you have identified the character, also try an online search engine to find out spellings easier for you, e.g., the romanized ones.

If everything else fails, ask the sources where you got the name from. The contact person can be an editor, a publisher, a coauthor, or the author himself/herself. Some authors maintain homepages with a correct spelling of their name; if it is the case for the author in question, take a look at their HTML code.

Comment: One very important addendum to this answer. *Detexify* does not recognize most characters from foreign alphabets. *Shapecatcher* does.

Answer (score 1):

Google the webpage of the author. If this is unicode, then cut and paste the special character into Google. Otherwise, find his name rendered in unicode somewhere on the internet, and Google the character. This should take you to a webpage that tells you what the character is. You can then Google to find out how to type it in your word processor. Or (depending on the word processor) you can just cut and paste the unicode.